# Xcode acts weird on Build and Debug

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm currently developing an iPhone app and so far things have worked out smoothly. However, tonight I've been getting some weird behavior from Xcode when choosing 'Build and Debug', especially when using the simulator. In simulator it seems I'm getting two builds of my app installed, there's two identical icons on the homescreen of the simulator, even if i delete both of them before building. On my device there's only one icon.
Also, when using breakpoints the debugger stops at them, but when i step through the code it seems my different variables aren't getting any values - which they definitely should.
I'm using Xcode 3.2.1 and my Active Configuration is set to 'Release'. I did create a distribution build about a week ago but things have been working since then.

So, what button did I mistakenly press here?

Thanks
Michael Frost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this happen if you use the Debug configuration? The Release configuration removes debugging symbols.

Comment: That did the trick! It seems it was a mixture of problems causing this. When choosing Debug I only got one version installed, and when double-checking some files again i found an old version of a resource file in my project. Don't know exactly what was wrong but it seems to be working as it should now.
Thanks!